# How to resolve Failed to connect to IPC Port Error

Tags: c#-4.0, wix

I am getting one issue in my application Setup USING wix

When i run my setup i got the below exception message:-

Failed to connect to IPC Port System cannot find the file specified:mscorlib.dll

After getting this message i got a windows message

There is a problem with this installer setup.
A program run as a part of system did not finish as expected.

Is there any way to resolve it.

Comment: It seems like problem is not in your msi but is in part of msi where you are trying to connect to IPC port.Please provide more info.Try if this link(Simple google search) work for you http://www.sqlinfo.in/2012/02/sql-server-fix-error-failed-connect-ipc-port-system-find-path-database-engine-tuning-advisor-dta/

Comment: Thank u Nimish that link did not work for me..
I will provide more information on this.

Answer (score 2):

Get to Dos command line then type in

Netsh winhttp show proxy   ( Press Enter )

then type in

Reset proxy ( Press Enter )

This will release the Internet Proxy IP settings,  restart the PC if needed.